# How do I update Ubuntu when package system is broken?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I have been trying to update Gallium OS (which is based on Ubuntu), however, I keep on getting error messages. Any help would be appreciated. Please see a screenshot of the error message below:

[image: Error message.]

I ran `sudo apt-get -f install` in terminal and received the following message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libssl1.0.0:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libssl1.0.0:i386
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,106 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 193560 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libssl1.0.0_1.0.2d-0ubuntu1.5-galliumos0_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libssl1.0.0:i386 (1.0.2d-0ubuntu1.5-galliumos0) over (1.0.2d-0ubuntu1.4-galliumos0) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2d-0ubuntu1.5-galliumos0_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libssl1.0.0/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libssl1.0.0:i386
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2d-0ubuntu1.5-galliumos0_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: try `sudo apt-get -f install` to force an install of the files that didn't get loaded because of the error.

Comment: I've actually tried that before. This is the response that I get:

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2d-0ubuntu1.5-galliumos0_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libssl1.0.0/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libssl1.0.0:i386
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2d-0ubuntu1.5-galliumos0_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Sorry if that looks a bit jumbled together.

Comment: please [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/290836/edit) your post and paste content requested by any user. this will help others too.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware that's how I was supposed to respond. Just updated the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible workaround would be to rename that directory, and force installation like this,

```
sudo mv /usr/share/doc/libssl1.0.0 /usr/share/doc/libssl1.0.0.backup
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Or this might also fix your problem,

```
apt-get install libssl1.0.0 libssl1.0.0:i386
```

Comment: specifying architectures (`i386` and `amd64`) to have the same version of package could have fix your problem.